# How to simulate requestAnimationFrame on non-supporting browsers properly?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cross-browser

Safari 5.1 and older browsers doesn't provide an `requestAnimationFrame` function, which is essential for some applications that use dynamic, JavaScript-based positioning. `setInterval` is not a satisfactory replacement as it lacks synchronization between updates and rendering. How to properly emulate `requestAnimationFrame` on those browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have another option than a timer. If you want to avoid possible dropped frames by `setInterval`, use `setTimeout`, and start a new timeout from the callback every time:

```
function renderFrame() {
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(renderFrame, 1000/30);
}
renderFrame();
```

---

Actually, my first sentence is not accurate. A Google search has shown me other options, such as [a timestamp-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398368/825789), and [another one that uses both timestamps and setTimeout](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671).

Comment: The renderFrame function is just not fast enough. I have elements positioned based on the scrolling of the page - and when a user scrolls, it vibrates, because the element is pushed up and NOT pushed back to it's right position fast enough. That is, two renderings happen without my refreshing function happening between them, which is really bad.

Comment: You could try this timestamp-based solution I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13398368/825789. Also, there are lots of google results for "requestAnimationFrame polyfill", maybe one of those will fit your requirements.

Comment: @Viclib: You just should exclude such elements from scrolling with CSS, instead of trying to animate them with JavaScript.

Comment: the timeout value should be zero of it's a rip-off of requestAnimationFrame. It might also want to check to see if the tab is even visible and discard the timeout if not, just like RAF...

Comment: @dandavis Sure, my answer is too simplistic, and possibly incorrect (although I was not aiming to provide a complete polyfill for RAF). However, I'm not sure if should delete it, considering it's currently the only answer to the question.